# Externalize properties in Kafka Connect

Tags: openshift, apache-kafka-connect

I want to externalize DB connection username and password in Kafka connect, the application is supposed to fetch username and password from OpenShift Secret config. Can someone guide how to do it please.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Connect can only externalize secrets to files.

You would need to [write your own `ConfigProvdier`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations) implementation to have different functionality.

Otherwise you could [mount a volume](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-secrets.html#nodes-pods-secrets-about-examples_nodes-pods-secrets)